# Gradle dependency conflict when using `implementation`

Tags: gradle

I have a project with two gradle modules: `lib` and `app`. I just changed `lib`'s build.gradle to stop exposing a dependency (i.e. I moved from `api` -> `implementation`). The `app` module doesn't directly depend on OkHttp logging interceptor so I figure it's better to not expose it.

`lib` module's build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    // api 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0'
    ...
}
```

`app` module's build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':lib')
    implementation group: 'com.zendesk', name: 'support-providers', version: '2.0.0'
    ...
}
```

However I'm now seeing a compile problem:

> Conflict with dependency 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor' in
>   project ':app'. Resolved versions for runtime classpath (3.10.0) and 
>   compile classpath (3.8.1) differ

If I look at project structure I see this:

```
+--- project :lib
...
+--- com.zendesk:support-providers:2.0.0
|    +--- com.zendesk:core:1.0.0
|    |    +--- com.zendesk:java-common:1.13
|    |    +--- com.google.dagger:dagger:2.12 -> 2.15 (*)
|    |    +--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0
|    |    |    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0 -> 3.8.1
|    |    |         \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0
|    |    +--- com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0
|    |    |    +--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7
|    |    +--- com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.1 // <----- SEE HERE
|    |    |    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1 (*) 
|    |    +--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2 -
```

`lib` isn't revealing any of it's dependencies (obviously) and `app` depends on Zendesk sdk which depends on *different* version of OkHttp logging interceptor.

I only see two ways to fix this:

1. revert `api -> implementation` in `lib` module, thus exposing logging interceptor to `app` module
2. declare a top level dependency on logging interceptor and set to 3.10 to force Zendesk to use latest:

`app` build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':lib')
    implementation group: 'com.zendesk', name: 'support-providers', version: '2.0.0'

    // used just to force zendesk to use 3.10
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0' 
    ...
}
```

Neither of these seem very clean. IMO the `app` module shouldn't know anything about OkHttp logging interceptor. Is there another option?

If Zendesk updated their library to use `implementation` for their OkHttp dependency would this solve the problem? Will Gradle let two dependencies use different versions of the same transitive dependency as long as they don't expose to the project as a whole?

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/managing_transitive_dependencies.html#sec:enforcing_dependency_version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

with Gradle this works a little different ...

one can either enforce the version `3.10.0`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation group: 'com.zendesk', name: 'support-providers', version: '2.0.0'
}

configurations.all() {
    resolutionStrategy.force "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0"
}
```

or just exclude version `3.8.1` (which is leaving nothing but the desired version `3.10.0`):

```
dependencies {
    implementation ('com.zendesk:support-providers:2.0.0") {
        exclude "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.1"
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I really didn't want app module to have to know about okhttp.

Comment: @Martin, it's a bit late but I have similar question. Here if forcing on 3.10.0, will it have side effect on the `com.zendesk`, since it was developed against 3.8.1. What if the forced version is incompatible with the original dependency? 
thanks!
 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72382560/gradle-is-there-difference-with-or-without-exclude-on-a-transitive-dependency

Comment: I've already outlined both options. "What if" is a barely rhetorical question - proof it. While I have the impression, that people may think that "latest" always means "best", while not caring about "compatible". Even when the public API might be slightly incompatible, it doesn't matter while not using any of the methods; ProGuard also complains when it cannot find methods.

Comment: One still could configure `transitive true`, which causes it to fetch.